# I installed KVM via synaptic from Ubuntu repositories, and now my computer won't boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, linux-kvm, android-studio

2 week old Ubuntu 18.04 install.

As a requirement of running a android device emulator for Android studio, I had to install KVM, so I installed it (the exact package name was kvm, it had some dependencies), and now my computer won't boot. It just sits there with a purple screen.

No keyboard or mouse input has any effect (including REISUB).

I have googled and nothing relevant comes up (it's all about booting VMs, understandably).

I have no idea what to do, especially since I cannot interact directly with my OS.

I still have my boot stick (that I used to install 18.04), and I can boot off that.

I have a picture of the packages I installed (I sent a picture of what I was doing to a friend to explain why it was taking so long to test their pull request), but stackexchange won't let me post it until I've got enough popularity points so I'll list the packages in the picture:

- linux-kvm
- linux-image-kvm
- linux-image-4.15.0-1011-kvm
- linux-headers-kvm
- linux-headers-4.15.0-1011-kvm
- linux-kvm-headers-4.15.0-1011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that installing linux-kvm actually doesn't install a VM program, it just installs another kernal that's obsolete, puts it at the top of the grub list, and that's how it breaks your computer.

I fixed it by using boot-repair (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).